# How can I get the user requesting a POST through Tastypie in a custom view

Tags: django, tastypie

Inside of a Django 1.5.5 project I am trying to allow mobile clients to bet on encounters through the Tastypie's API. After reading POST datas I can then save the `Bet` object, but I need the `User` instance for that matter.

I know `bundle.request.user` but this reference isn't available in custom views (used with `prepend_urls` like here.

In my custom view, `request.user` refers to `AnonymousUser`. The API resources are protected using Tastypie's `ApiKeyAuthentication` (do I need to get the current `User` with the API key located in the header ?).

```py
# ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
class BaseResource(ModelResource):

    # ──────────────────────────────────────
    def prepend_urls(self):
        try:
            additional_urls = self._meta.additional_urls
        except AttributeError:
            additional_urls = []
        return [url(r'^'+u[0]+'$', self.wrap_view(u[1]), name=u[2]) for u in additional_urls]

    ...

    # ──────────────────────────────────────
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        allowed_methods = ['get',]
        authentication  = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization   = DjangoAuthorization()
        max_limit = 1000
```

```py
# ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
class EncounterResource(BaseResource):

    ...

    # ──────────────────────────────────────
    def bet(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        encounter = int(kwargs.get('encounter', 0))
        if not encounter:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'message': 'Pretty sure you\'re doing something wrong',
            }, HttpApplicationError)
        data = self.deserialize(
            request,
            request.body,
            format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')
        )
        ...
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': True,
        }, HttpCreated)

    # ──────────────────────────────────────
    class Meta(BaseResource.Meta):
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post',]
        queryset      = Encounter.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'encounters'
        additional_urls = [
            ('encounters/(?P<encounter>\d+)/bet/', 'bet', 'api-encounter-bet'),
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how "dispatch" does it. You want to call the `is_authenticated` method first, and then you can use request.user

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L443

Comment: After reading what does `is_authenticated` I don't see how it can help me have my current user rather than AnonymousUser. In my case being *signed in* merely means having the ApiKey string saved in the mobile client since I don't use `django.contrib.auth.authenticate`. This string is then passed on with every request through HTTP headers. I am currently identifying current user with the ApiKey located in the headers and it is working, but I suspect this isn't the good practice to handle such an easy task.

Comment: But I am probably completely missing the point here, what I want to do is to make available to mobile clients the same features as the website's. So instead of letting every resources opened to PATCH and PUT, I thought it would be a good idea to use `prepend_urls` have some *helpers* for the API users.

Comment: is_authenticated sets the request.user based on the ApiKey authentication. after the method is called, if it passes, you can use request.user to get the current user, if it fails HttpNotAuthorized will be returned.

Comment: Are we talking about this very [`is_authenticated`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L533) ?

Comment: We are. It calls self._meta.authentication.is_authenticated, which for you is this function:

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L176

Which on this line, sets request.user to the authenticated user.

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L205-L206

Comment: Ok I'll try this tonight (3:30AM here). Also, I think I misunderstood what being signed in means: I should call "authenticate" when a client sign in through the API. I'll write an answer or edit yours as soon as I fix my issue. Thanks

Comment: This has nothing to do with calling `authenticate` when signing in. As pointed out, the `is_authenticated` call is enough. Thanks